# Regex to validate 3 specific forms of a phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

So I am trying to write code that will evaluate if a phone number is valid in one of three ways.

The first is the form xxx-xxx-xxxx, the second is (xxx) xxx-xxxx, and the third is xxxxxxxxxx.

Here's my regular expression:

```
if (/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/.test(phoneVal) || /^\d{10}$/.test(phoneVal) || /^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$/.test(phoneVal)) {
           return true;
     }
```

However whenever I put in what I would consider to be a valid phone number, it trips up this regular expression, and gives the error:

```
else {
         alert("Please put in a correct phone number");
         return false;
     }
```

Comment: Is it failing in all 3 formats or just one specific format?  Also, you're sure there's no leading/trailing spaces?

Comment: All three formats. There shouldn't be any leading or trailing spaces, it's a simple text input box.

Comment: Your RegEx seems to be fine. Maybe you need to trim() the string? Or, you're triggering the event before the string is entered?

Comment: It should be triggered on submit, when all the values are already inputted.

Comment: Hmm... try hard coding phoneVal just before the if block to something like "123-456-7890".  If it still breaks, then we know for sure that it's the regex, if it works, then it's probably whatever gathers the input.
Also, for a little background, is this in a function to validate phone numbers or is it part of a larger hunk of code?

Comment: I will try trimming the string.

Comment: It's part of a function that first validates that there is input into multiple boxes, and then once that is done, it validates that a correct phone number was submitted.

Comment: Make sure you're testing on keyup rather than keydown.

Comment: Hard coded seemed to work, so now the question is how is the input getting screwed up. Let me alert what phoneVal is and see.

Comment: keyup versus keydown? I'm new to Javascript and am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Have you considered replacing `\s(-` then checking against a `^\d{10}$`

Comment: @antisanity - I think he said that he's triggering it on form submit, not keyup or keydown.  Hopefully that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: When running this:      phoneVal = document.getElementById("phone");
     alert(phoneVal); I get: [Object HTML InputElement]

Comment: The name of this question is pretty lame. A better title wuold be something like _Regex to validate 3 specific forms of a phone number?_

Comment: Changed it. Now it looks better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When running this: phoneVal = document.getElementById("phone");
>   alert(phoneVal); I get: [Object HTML InputElement]

You're getting the element rather than its value. Use the `value` property:

```
phoneVal = document.getElementById("phone").value;
```

Comment: I should probably try alerting my variables more often.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander I find logging them to the console way more useful ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tested function which meets your requirements:

```js
// Validate 10 digit US phone number in one of three specific formats.
function validatePhoneNumber(text) {
    /*  # Validate US phone number in one of three specific formats.
        ^                                   # Anchor to start of string.
        (?:                                 # Group alternatives.
          [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}        # Either xxx-xxx-xxxx
        | \([0-9]{3}\)[ ][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}  # or (xxx) xxx-xxxx
        | [0-9]{10}                         # or xxxxxxxxxx
        )                                   # End group of alternatives.
        $                                   # Anchor to end of string.
    */
    var re = /^(?:[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}|\([0-9]{3}\)[ ][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{10})$/;
    return re.test(text);
}
```

That said, as others have pointed out, you should allow users to input a more loosely defined number. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8404272/433790) to your other (nearly identical) question which is more forgiving.

Answer (score 0):

I think when it comes to phone numbers you need to give you're users freedom to write the number in one of their own prefered format.

The regex below matches ##########, ###.###.####, ###-###-####, ### ### ####, (###) ### ####, (###)-###-#### and many more combinations.

```
if(/\(?\b[0-9]{3}\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}\b/.test(phoneVal))
{
    return true;
} else
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For phone numbers, I tend to strip out any characters that's not A-Z, 0-9, and then make sure the result is numeric, and 10 digits long.  Some people use periods, dashes, brackets, spaces, etc.  `1-23--4..5@678_9%0` would be a valid phone number, but when I store it in the database, I normalize it to `1234567890`, and then when presenting it back, I format it myself in the format of my own choosing, such as `123-456-7890`.