# A function to test a regular expression and change the text if it does not fit

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use an if statement to determine if a certain variable in PHP ($phone) matches a regular expression. There are three different options - it either passes it correctly, it is a mostly correct value and just needs some slight modifications, and finally, that it is an an erroneous value and should go back to the previous page with an error message. Here's what I've got so far:

EDIT: The expected value of $phone is either 123-456-7890, 1234567890, or (123) 456-7890. The desired input for the database is 123-456-7890

```
if (preg_match("/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/", $phone)) {
    // This is the 100% correct version
}
else if (preg_match("/^\d{10}$/", $phone)) {
    $phone = preg_replace("/^(.{3})/", "-", $phone);
    $phone = preg_replace("/^(.{6})/", "-", $phone);
// This is one of the mostly correct - this does not seem to work. I got a value of -37 when I tried to use it
}
else if (preg_match("/^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$/", $phone)) {
    // Have not tried anything here, because the problems here are similar to the else if statement above
}
else {
    header('Location: '.$admin.'?error=phone');
// This should direct back to the previous page with an error message.
}
```

EDIT 2: Ok I've got the if and the else ifs working, however the else does not redirect back to the page or prevention insertion into the database. How do I do this?

Comment: Mmmm, you should tell us at least what's the input (`$phone`) and what's the expected output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$phone = preg_replace("/^(\d{3})(\d{3})/", "$1-$2-", $phone);
```

and for the second

```
$phone = preg_replace("/^\((\d{3})\) /", "$1-", $phone);
```

**Explanation:**

```
/         : regex delimiter
^         : start of the string
(\d{3})   : group 1 capture 3 digits
(\d{3})   : group 2 capture 3 next digits
/
```

**replacement part :**

```
$1        : value captured in group 1 (the first 3 digits)
-         : a dash
$2        : value captured in group 2 (the next 3 digits)
-         : a dash
```

For dealing with all test cases, I'd do:

```
// Remove all non digit
$phone = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $phone);
// then we must have a 10 digit number
if (preg_match('/^\d{10}$/', $phone) {
    $phone = preg_replace("/^(\d{3})(\d{3})/", "$1-$2-", $phone);
} else {
    // error
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the regular expressions are doing in each case? I'm not sure what the "$1-$2-" means.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it all in one regex, with something like this regex and [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace).

```
\(?(\d{3})[)-]?\s?(\d{3})-?(\d{4})
```

An explanation of the regex (most likely can be improved):

```
\(? // Optionally match the left parenthesis
(\d{3}) // Match 3 digits, capture those digits into backreference #1
[)-]?   // Optionally match one of the characters: right parenthesis or dash
\s?     // Optionally match a space
(\d{3}) // Match 3 digits, capture those digits into backreference #2
-?      // Optionally match the dash
(\d{4}) // Match 4 digits, capture those digits into backreference #3
```

And an explanation of the replacement:

```
$1-$2-$3
```

This means to take the values captured from the above backreferences and place them in the string, each separated with dashes.

See the [demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yYsK8Y) to see that it passes all the test cases.

**Edit:** To detect an invalid format, just check to make sure what you get back from the replacement is in the valid format, like so:

```
$replace = preg_replace( '#\(?(\d{3})[)-]?\s?(\d{3})-?(\d{4})#i', '$1-$2-$3', $test);
if( !preg_match('/\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/', $replace))
{
    // Redirect
}
```

Comment: What about the else statement, though?

Comment: @AndrewAlexander - Easy! Check the return from the replacement to see if its in the expected format. I've added an example and updated the demo, which now only requires two regexes and does not use multiple calls to `preg_match` or `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$phone = '(555) 555-5555';

//ONLY CHECK IF IT DOESNT MATCH
if ( !preg_match( '/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/', $phone ) )
{
  //CHECK FOR SOLID 10 NUMBERS
  if( preg_match( '/^\d{10}$/', $phone ) )
  {
    preg_match( '/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/', $phone, $matches );
    $phone = $matches[1].'-'.$matches[2].'-'.$matches[3];
  }
  //CHECK FOR BRACKET/DASH VERSION
  elseif( preg_match( '/^\(\d{3}\)\ \d{3}-\d{4}$/', $phone ) )
  {
    preg_match( '/^\((\d{3})\) (\d{3})-(\d{4})$/i', $phone, $matches );
    $phone = $matches[1].'-'.$matches[2].'-'.$matches[3];
  }
  else
  {
    header('Location: '.$admin.'?error=phone');
  }
}

echo $phone;
```

A smaller version is:

```
//ONLY CHECK IF IT DOESNT MATCH
if ( !preg_match( '/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/', $phone ) )
{
  if( preg_match( '/^(?:\((\d{3})\) (\d{3})-(\d{4}))|(?:(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4}))$/', $phone, $matches ) )
  {
    if( !empty( $matches[1] ) )
    {
      $phone = $matches[1].'-'.$matches[2].'-'.$matches[3];
    }
    else
    {
      $phone = $matches[4].'-'.$matches[5].'-'.$matches[6];
    }
  }
  else
  {
    header('Location: '.$admin.'?error=phone');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tested function showing how I'd do it:

```php
// Return tidied up 10 digit US phone number or FALSE if invalid.
function validateAndTidyPhoneNumber($text) {
    $re = '/ # Match loosely formatted US phone number.
        ^           # Anchor to start of string.
        \s*         # Allow leading whitespace.
        \(?         # First digit set may be inside ().
        ([0-9]{3})  # $1: 3 digits (1st set).
        \)?         # First digit set may be inside ().
        [ -]*       # Allow space or dash separators.
        ([0-9]{3})  # $2: 3 digits (2nd set).
        [ -]*       # Allow space or dash separators.
        ([0-9]{4})  # $3: 4 digits (3rd set).
        \s*         # Allow trailing whitespace.
        $           # Anchor to end of string.
        /ix';
    // Tidy up phone number.
    $text = preg_replace($re, '$1-$2-$3', $text);
    // Return tidied-up phone number if in correct format.
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/', $text)) {
        return $text;
    }
    return FALSE; // Otherwise bad phone number.
}
```